# Number of elements of an array

Tags: matlab

I want to found how many elements in an array is not equal to zero. I use this code:

```
y=sum(img_dct~=0);
z=sum(y);
```

Can i make this with a different way? Is there a matlab instruction like 'numel' that can do the job?

Comment: Question is off-topic for DSP.SE - programming questions belong on http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one command by first using the colon operator to cast the matrix to a column vector.

```
z = sum(img_dict(:) ~= 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Prize for using `numel`?

```
z=numel(find(img_dct));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Matlab, there is a built-in command to do just this.

`nnz(y)`

Answer (score 1):

You should get the number of how many elements are not equal to zero directly by

```
z=sum(img_dct~=0);
```

Comment: I take an array after this command and then i need to use again 'sum' to take the length of array.